# Report templates for Team Foundation Server 2008

Tags: tfs

Does anybody have links to site or pre built report running on the SQL Analysis Service provided by TFS2008?

Creating a meaningful Excel report or a new report sometime is a very boring and difficult taks, maybe finding a way to share reports could be a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this download: [Creating and Customizing TFS Reports](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a74486b2-f7db-4a85-97bd-46bf478bda60&displaylang=en), it includes a few samples and some guidance. [More here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc487893.aspx).

Also try the [TFS Reporting Samples.zip](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2006/09/09/tfs-reporting.aspx) linked from this site.

This site links to a large number of TFS reporting resources:
http://blogs.msdn.com/teams_wit_tools/archive/2007/03/26/tfs-report-developer-resources.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SCRUM, this has Sprint reports and Product Burndown reports:

http://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/en/default.aspx